# Understanding the proof of $4I.1$ in Hatcher's

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

**The statement**. If $X,Y$ are $CW$ complexes, then $\Sigma (X\times Y)$ is homotopically equivalent to $\Sigma X\vee \Sigma Y\vee \Sigma (X\wedge Y)$.
Here $\Sigma$ means the reduced suspension.
The proof is along the lines mentioned in [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/865760/266435).

**Questions**. I don't understand the following in the proof:

1. Why do they take reduced join, i.e., why won't the join work?
2. What is a reduced join geometrically?
3. How is a reduced join different from the actual join?
4. Why does contracting $CX$ and $CY$ result in $\Sigma(X\times Y)$?
5. Why does contracting $X*y_0$ and $x_0*Y$ result in $\Sigma X \vee \Sigma (X\wedge Y)\vee \Sigma Y$?

Can anyone please explain me the proof? I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: There are too many questions in your post. You need to narrow things down, either by thinking a bit more about it or starting with one of the questions and later tackling the others. On another note, 4. is already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662485/understanding-why-collapsing-cx-and-cy-gives-us-sum-x-times-y?rq=1) for example. Did you try reading that? There is a very good answer there that should help.

Comment: @Pedro: No, I hadn't seen that post. Thanks for sharing. I'll go through it.